# FFmpeg write silence if there is no data in pipe:0

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have an ffmpeg process that continiously writes `PCM` data from standard input to an `mp3` file. I receive voice data from remote UDP voice server that handles user's voices. If user is speaking - data is sent. Immediately after I receive voice, I write it to ffmpeg standard input. But I don't receive any data if user is not speaking. And this holes might be very large, but I never stop ffmpeg process unless receiving is manually stopped. I want to get ffmpeg to write silence to file if there is no data in `pipe:0`. Is it possible to do only with ffmpeg or I need to implement it on my side? If it is possible, then how can I do that? I tried to use some parameters and filters but I didn't find the thing I need.

I tried to use `lavfi` and `anullsrc` using this command:

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -re -i anullsrc=r=48000:cl=mono -f s16le -ac {Channels} -ar 48000 -i pipe:0 -f segment -segment_time {SegmentSize} -segment_list \"{SegmentListPath}\" -segment_format mp3 -segment_wrap 2 -reset_timestamps 0 -shortest \"{FilePathFormat}\"
```

but it doesn't work.

I'm new to ffmpeg and working with audio so I will be glad to see any assistance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried to use `lavfi` and `anullsrc`"? What command did you use?

Comment: @TheRandomGuyNamedJoe12 I used command `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -re -i anullsrc=r=48000:cl=mono -f s16le -ac {Channels} -ar 48000 -i pipe:0 -f segment -segment_time {SegmentSize} -segment_list \"{SegmentListPath}\" -segment_format mp3 -segment_wrap 2 -reset_timestamps 0 -shortest \"{FilePathFormat}\"`.
I have a problem with this command that for to some reason it starts processing data only when I close standard input stream, that means that it only writes silence infinitely without any data from pipe:0.

Comment: @OleksandrPetrenko I haven't tried this but it will probably work `ffmpeg -y -re -f s16le -ac {Channels} -ar 48000 -i pipe:0 -f segment -segment_time {SegmentSize} -segment_list \"{SegmentListPath}\" -segment_format mp3 -segment_wrap 2 -reset_timestamps 0 -shortest -filter:a "apad" \"{FilePathFormat}\"`

Comment: @TheRandomGuyNamedJoe12 yes, that worked. But it may be inaccurate. It writed ~29 seconds instead of ~32. All my voice data piped is written with no problems, but it writed not enough silence. I would like to have something more accurate, because every second is important in my case. Could you suggest something else?